# Command works if run through the command prompt but not in a script..?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to script the installation of a number of patches using a batch file since powershell doesn't properly install the patches.  The command I'm running is this:

```
dism /online /add-package /PackagePath:"C:\<path>\5cbb03ca-7a2a-4326-952f-80ad8052a886\windows6.1-kb2836942-x64-express.cab"
```

That works perfectly when run directly from the command line.  But if I put it in a file called `example.bat` it fails with the following message:

```
'þd' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your batch file is saved as Unicode.

Re-open it in Notepad and re-save it, making sure the Encoding field is set to ANSI.

Comment: That's possible because I'm redirecting output to a file using powershell `>>`.  Is there a way to specify the encoding using powershell when redirecting output this way?

Comment: Instead of using `>>` use `out-File` it has an `-Encoding` switch, which defaults to Unicode.