# Copying a batch file to another location

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to copy a batch file into another location, I've looked into the copy commands in cmd and tried to use " Xcopy" and "Copy" but I wasn't sure how to use them, this is what i got to so far

```
copy test.bat C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Hello test.bat
```

My problem is with the source and destination..I'm having trouble trying to understand the format of the copy  command

Edit:

(1) I'm running my test.bat file from the command prompt windows

(2) The test.bat is in the following: C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Bold

Comment: Is "Hello" the name of a directory, or is "Hello test.bat" the name of the file you want to create?

Comment: "Hello" is the name of the file containing the "test.bat"

Comment: I don't understand -- it is either a directory (which contains files) or a file (which contains text).  Post the contents of the file "Hello", that would help

Comment: @Scarl Edit your question and show us the **(1)** directory you are executing the copy command from and **(2)** the directory that `test.bat` is in. The `COPY` command will give you an error if it can find the file to copy or if you don't have access to the destination directory.

Comment: What directory are you in when you run the command? You're command prompt will look something like `C:\Somefolder>`.

Comment: @aphoria it's the same directory, like in the c drive..I made sure im running the test.bat file by typing the full path of my test files's location

Comment: Does your command prompt window show `C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Bold` as your current directory?

Comment: @aphoria Yes, it does

Comment: You don't have a batch file named `COPY.BAT` do you?

Comment: @aphoria Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64333/discussion-between-scarl-and-aphoria).

Comment: I can't chat from my current location...blocked by firewall. :(

Comment: @aphoria that's doesn't sound good, you can have that as an exception in your firewall, can't you edit your settings?

Comment: It's the corporate firewall...I have no control over it.

Comment: @aphoria I tried to perform the copy command in the command prompt and it worked, however when i try to type the command in my test.bat file it's not working :s

Comment: Maybe this question is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145540/command-works-if-run-through-the-command-prompt-but-not-in-a-script/19145733#19145733

Comment: @aphoria thanks a alot! it's finally working! :D

Answer (score 0):

If "Hello" is the name of the destination directory, then do:

```
copy test.bat C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Hello\test.bat
```

If "Hello test.bat" is the name of the destination file, then put quotes around it to handle the filename containing a space:

```
copy test.bat "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Hello test.bat"
```

These both assume that your command prompt's current directory is where the source "test.bat" resides.  If not, you can specify the full path for both the source & destination:

```
copy C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Bold\test.bat C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Hello\test.bat
```

Comment: and how will the compiler know where the " test.bat" file is in my computer to copy it? (  I'm sorry but that's the confusing part for me)

Comment: @Scarl If you don't specify the location, it will assume the current directory.

Comment: Okay, I tried the first one where "Hello" is the name of the destination, but it's not copying the file

Comment: @aphoria nope, it's just not copying

Comment: After the copy can you do "dir C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Hello\test.bat"?

Comment: @JohnD for your updated answer, where does the file go in that syntax? ( the last piece of code you added)